# How to auto update unit/integration test details on Jira issue on push?

Tags: git, unit-testing, junit, jira, jira-agile

To automate certain steps of Jira life cycle in our team, we need a way to automatically update unit or integration test details on Jira. So Jira approver can be sure of that some kind of test is added to reproduce the issue and test solution (Kind of testing evidence). Jira integration with GitHub can already provide branch, commit, files changed, pull requests etc on Jira. Wondering if we can take it to next level and show test info as well.

On git push -> update no of unit test added with commit in Jira.

any suggestions on if there is plugin already which can do it or on approach?

Comment: Which CI server are you using?

Comment: Jenkins @StefanBirkner

Comment: There are a few plugins that can publish test results to JIRA (search for "jenkins plugin test result jira").